# How to determine a server installation is completed remotely

Tags: linux, bash, installation, remote-server, linode

I use linode to install Debian using an automatic ISO installer with preseed file. Once the operating system is installed on the remote machine, it has a final command that it will restart the OS automatically using the preseed command like this:

```
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

So, is there a programmatically way to determine that the operating system has successfully installed on linode via my local machine?

One idea that I can think of is that, I can create a bash script with while loop to determine if the server port 22 is open, then it has finished installed. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
 :
if [ linode_server_port_22_is_open ]; then
  echo "Installation has finished" #because port 22 is open
  break; # break the loop
else
  # PORT 22 is not open, sleep 10 seconds before re-check next loop
  echo "Checking installation progress in the next 10 seconds ..."
  sleep 10
fi
done
```

The code is just a prototype but is there a better way of doing this ?

Also, I'm able to run any scripts right before the Debian OS has finished install on the linode remote machine. I'm looking for a better way to determine how can the remote machine tell me that it has finished install operating system instead of detecting the opening port 22 of remote SSH.

Is there a way for the remote machine to broadcast its status that it has finished install?

USE CASE:

The reason I want this is, from the start I already implemented a script that will create an ISO with preseed.cfg, then it automatically upload this ISO file into linode in rescue mode (script can put the linode in rescue mode), then it extract the ISO to install the Operating system. So, from zero (creating new linode DISK, configuration) now it's the part to determine if the OS has finished installed. If I can determine OS has finished installed then I will be able to login into the server automatically and install Directadmin remotely. So, my aim is to run one script to deploy a server from zero on linode until I got a full Directadmin is installed with ready website (I have done the Directadmin part). Now the only issue is how to determine the operating system has finished installed so I can use the status to continue my script for the other automation function.

Comment: The easiest would be to have a simple web service sitting somewhere on the internet which you ping with a simple wget call and that in turn sends you an email

Comment: Thanks, but using `wget` what kind of data should I obtain from the remote machine to determine it has finished installed? Is there a way for the remote machine to broadcast its status that it has finished install?

Comment: if is an iso then scripted cloud-init style and it reboots etc once its all installed and ready, you could make a file and then delete it after its next booted, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/156771/run-a-script-only-at-the-very-first-boot imo though if you set up monitoring as part of setup, then its going to pop up in the monitoring panel which ever you use, also you could ping a service port like your doing, or you could do reverse shell, but its all more code/steps then simply wget'ing a url

Comment: *"Thanks, but using wget what kind of data should I obtain from the remote machine to determine it has finished installed?"* - Anything.  Just replying to a GET with a 200 response should be enough to prove that the webserver is alive.